# excel file is not getting created using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create excel using javascript, i am using below code to do so.

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");  
var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;  
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "This is column A, row 1";  
ExcelSheet.SaveAs("C:\\raj\TEST.xls");  
ExcelSheet.Application.Quit();
```

Somebody please point out where am making mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I came to know that, this works only in IE, doesnt work in chrome or firefox.